# How to set up a Pypi package without the dot notation in absolute import - python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module, pypi

Most "professional" python modules can be imported like so:

```
from pythonfile import class
```

And that is how I usually import my own classes that are in my local file system/current directory.

But after looking at several posts and python.org documents, I still can't get my python module (on Pypi.org) to import like that.

The only way I can get my module to import is like so:

```
from example.example import Example
```

(Example is a class within example.py)

How to I get my module to import like so:

```
from example import Example
```

My module on Pypi has a folder structure is like this and installs fine via pip:

```
example/
|
├── example/
│   ├── example.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
|
|
├── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
|
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

- I've omitted the build/, dist/, and egg-info directories for clarity.

Should I add import statements to one of the `__init__.py` files?

I want developers to be able to install the package via pip, and then use a simple

`from example import Example` and not `from example.example import Example`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you have a look at some other big packages they usually have in their top __init__.py something like

```
from .modulex import *
from .moduley import *
```

the dot means, python is looking in current package before rest of the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: but which __init__.py should that go on? The one in the top directory? Or the one inside the inner example/ directory?

Comment: the one in the top directory. in your case you write from .example import Example. but you have to install it to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. The answer may have been in some other posts I think but they had too much extra information:D I ended up using   from .example import Example on the __init__.py file

Comment: you are welcome! But it's just that i'm too lazy. I think there are lot's of pitfalls with imports in packages one could mention here.